# utc_timestamp() is inserting date as its in my system. Not UTC date

Tags: php, mysql

I have used `utc_timestamp()`to insert time and date into database. a while ago executed a query and checked the time and date in database. the time was correct as it was 8 p.m utc. but the date was 28. I am in Pakistan so its 28 here but in utc its still 27. So what is the issue?

I am in development environment on my own system.

**Update**

I ran this command `SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP);` and it gave me `-07:00:00`

Comment: what are server configurations of time where your mysql is running?

Comment: I am relatively new to php and mysql.. so don't know much about the server configuration.